How to make turtle in python turn in direction it is moving?
So I am making a drawing game where the user clicks to move the turtle towards their cursor. However, the turtle always looks in the same direction no matter where it is moving, which looks weird. How do I make the turtle turn in the direction of the cursor?
Here is my code:
def go_to(x, y):
  user.goto(x, y)

screen.onclick(go_to)

I have tried tiltangle and tilt but they do not seem to work in the way I was expecting.

Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The turtle needs to turn to face the cursor before moving. You can achieve this by using the setheading method to set the direction the turtle should face based on the coordinates of the cursor.
Here's the corrected code:
import turtle

def go_to(x, y):
    user.setheading(user.towards(x, y))
    user.goto(x, y)

screen = turtle.Screen()
user = turtle.Turtle()

screen.onclick(go_to)
screen.mainloop()


@Salt Why didn't you make this an answer? Also, you didn't get this from ChatGPT, did you?

@AndrewYim I didnt make this an answer because I've already answered another question in the last 30 minutes and I dont have enough reputation yet to answer more often..

@Salt thank you for your answer! That worked very well and is what I wanted.

See this answer: "If you're planning on moving your turtle to an (x, y) point somewhere and you want to point your turtle towards that point first, you can use: turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x, y))".
